# Hibernate tries to persist child twice after setting parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

I've got such Hibernate mapping:

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Valid
private Set<Assignment> assignments;
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
@Valid
private Parent parent;
```

I've got such situation: Parent is already persisted in database, I get new Assignments list. I make such thing (using Spring Data JPA):

```
parent.getAssignments().addAll(newAssignments);
parent.getAssignments().forEach(assignment -> assignment.setParent(parent));
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

I've got @PrePersist annotated method in base entity (extended by both), with validation that checks if createdDate, which is initialized in @PrePersist is not null. Base entity contains:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "created_date")
protected LocalDateTime createdDate;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    setModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    validateEntity();
}

private void validateEntity() {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<BaseEntity>> violations = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(this);
    if(!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(new ValidationMessageBuilder().build(violations));
    }
}
```

I've checked the objects under debugger, and for example Assignment is object @17609 and Parent is @17608.

Exception is raised, after invoking save() method.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: may not be null => com.foo.bar.model.domain.Assignment.parent.assignments.createdDate.
at com.foo.bar.model.BaseEntity.validateEntity(BaseEntity.java:70)
at com.foo.bar.model.BaseEntity.prePersist(BaseEntity.java:58)
```

I've debugged and in @PrePersist method of Assignment entity Hibernate invokes it for another object, which is Assignment@17646, which contains Parent@17608, and parent contains collection of children with one element, which is @17609.

Why hibernate tries to persist another object?

Comment: I think that you should only add assignements to parent and persist parent ,no need to set parent to assignement

Comment: What Kind of Exception are you getting... Can you post it?

Comment: @Antoniossss, if I don't set parent, hibernate is not doing this automatically and tries to persist assignment with parentId = null, which is not correct. If I change entity relations and add nullable="false" in Assignment's parent mapping then hibernate tries to do the same (set parent to assignment) and same exception occurs.

Comment: @CarlitosWay edited and added exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are my observations to your problem:

1. The Exception being thrown is not from Hibernate... it is being
   thrown by your validation method: `validateEntity()`, because your
   child assigments have a `null createDate`.
2. You're using `EntityListeners` for setting your `createdDate` and
   `modifiedDate` and validating your bean values... However, it seems
   (and this is me guessing) that your validation method is iterating
   (and validating) over the child assigments long before hibernate
   executes the `@PrePersist` on them!

My Suggestions to fix the problem:

1. Use this configuration:

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", CascadeType = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Set<Assignment> assignments;
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

BaseClass: Rename your `prePersist` method as:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void prePersistOrUpdate() {
    setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    setModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    validateEntity();
}
```

2. Check (and modify if required) your base validation method. This
   method should only validate the instance variables (as
   `createdDate`) and avoid transverse child objects that will be
   modified later for the `EntityListener` Method:
   `prePersistOrUpdate()` (Beware, I remove the `@Valid` annotation
   because I don't know for what it is used for... may be It is used by
   your validation framework).
3. Modify the business logic (where the `newAssigments`) are persisted
   as this:

   `parent.getAssignments().addAll(newAssignments);`
   `parent.getAssignments().forEach(assignment -> assignment.setParent(parent));`
   `parentRepository.merge(parent); // This should cascade and persist the new assigments!`

Comment: You were right - the problem was all in validation. After some alterations everything is working fine!